# En un servidor compartido como acceder a Storage si el proyecto esta en una subcarpeta?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

He logrado linkear mi carpeta storage con la carpeta public en mi servidor, pero uso el Facade Storage para guardar archivos y fotos, tengo mi proyecto y mi carpeta publica a la misma altura, es decir

```
/home/rootuser/public_html/Laravel //proyecto
/home/rootuser/public_html/sistemaDD/index.php, etc... //contenido de la carpeta public
```

Al momento de acceder con `<a href="{{ Storage::url($e->pdf) }}" target="_blank">Ver</a>`  Intenta buscar desde la raiz del proyecto no desde la carpeta publica ya mencionada antes. es decir

`<a href="/storage/ema/Laragon SSL.pdf" target="_blank">Ver</a> //Esta ruta es la que devuelve una en la pagina`

Si manualmente coloco

`<a href="/sistemaDD/storage/ema/Laragon SSL.pdf" target="_blank">Ver</a>`

logra hacerlo sin problemas pero ese no es el caso

en mi archivo `.env` tengo bien la ruta de mi servidor por ej. `miservidor.com/sistemaDD`

Habra alguna manera de cambiar esta ruta para que pueda acceder a los archivos y fotos?

```
configfilesystems.php

'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

Comment: Probaste con `{{ asset('Storage::url('$file->pdf')) }}`?

Comment: Si, perdon puse mal esa linea, de echo asi como lo comentaste asi mismo lo tengo

Comment: Por defecto laravel usa el disco local, que no trae la llave url, prueba con el disco public `Storage::disk('public')->url($file->pdf);`. Revisa que tienes en el archivo `/config/filesystems.php`

Comment: Agrego mi `config/filesystems.php`